# Mark values from loop for each iteration

Tags: matlab

I want to mark each value that comes out of my loop with a value.

Say I have a variable number of values that come out of each iteration. I want those values to be labeled by which iteration they came out of.

like 
1-1,
2-1,
3-1,

1-2,
2-2,
3-2,
4-2,

etc.

where the first number is the value from the loop and the second is counting which iteration it came from.
I feel like there is a way I just cant find it.

ok so here is some code.

```
for c=1:1:npoints;
    for i=1:1:NN;
        if ((c-1)*spacepoints)<=PL(i+1) && ((c-1)*spacepoints)>=PL(i);
            local(c)=((c)*spacepoints)-PL(i); 

        end
        if ((c-1)*spacepoints)>=PL(NN);
            local(c)=((c)*spacepoints)-PL(NN);
            element(i)=NN;
        end

    end
```

I want to mark each local value with the iteration it came from for the i:NN. PL is a vector and the output is a set of vectors for each iteration.

Comment: what type of value do you currently have? Post some code that we can work with! :)

Comment: I added some code. Please let me know if there is anything else that would help. I am fairly new to matlab and am not sure what this would be called. Essentially 1:NN is a the set I need the value "local" marked with.

Comment: @user618204: I added an answer below. Also note that using a variable name such as "local" is probably not a good habit to get in programming. Perhaps "local" is not usually a keyword, and it is not a keyword in MATLAB, but it is the direct opposite of "global" (and hence in family with it) and that is a keyword in MATLAB. Just a thought.

Comment: oh, I only used local because that is what i am finding. The local coordinates from global coordinates. Note taken though. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently as it is right now, in your inner `1:NN` loop, your `local(c)` variable is being updated or overwritten. You never apply the previous value of `local`, so it is not some iterative optimization algorithm(?)...

Perhaps an easy solution is to change the size/type of `local` from a *vector* to a *matrix*. Let's say that `local` is of size `[npoints 1]`. Instead you make it of size `[npoints NN]`. It is now a 2d-array (a matrix of `npoints` rows and `NN` columns). use the second dimension to store each (assumed column) vector from the inner loop:

```
local = zeros([npoints NN]);

%# ... code in bewteen ...

for c=1:1:npoints;
    for i=1:1:NN;
       if ((c-1)*spacepoints)<=PL(i+1) && ((c-1)*spacepoints)>=PL(i);
           local(c, i)=((c)*spacepoints)-PL(i); 

       end
       if ((c-1)*spacepoints)>=PL(NN);
           local(c, i)=((c)*spacepoints)-PL(NN);
           element(i)=NN;
       end

   end
end
```

The *c'th* row of your `local` matrix will then corresponds to the NN values from the inner loop. Please note that I have assumed your vector to be a column vector - if not, just change the order of the sizes.

Answer (score 2):

For this sort of quick problem I like to create a cell array:

```
for k = 1:12
    results{k} = complicated_function(...);
end
```

If the output is really complicated, then I return a struct with fields relating to the outputs:

```
for k = 1:12
     results{k}.file = get_filename(...);
     results{k}.result = ...;
end
```